# example code giving AttributeError: 'AdamOptimizer' object has no attribute '_beta1_power'

Tags: python, debugging, tensorflow

I am trying to run the example [./quick_scripts/celebA_superres.sh "./images/182659.jpg"](https://github.com/AshishBora/csgm) under Demo section. I am new to python and getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'AdamOptimizer' object has no attribute '_beta1_power'

As best I understand, an instance of an object called 'AdamOptimizer' does not know what to do with this type of variable. The code is the following:

```
def get_opt_reinit_op(opt, var_list, global_step):
    opt_slots = [opt.get_slot(var, name) for name in opt.get_slot_names() for var in var_list]
    if isinstance(opt, tf.train.AdamOptimizer):
        opt_slots.extend([opt._beta1_power, opt._beta2_power])  #pylint: disable = W0212
    all_opt_variables = opt_slots + var_list + [global_step]
    opt_reinit_op = tf.variables_initializer(all_opt_variables)
    return opt_reinit_op
```

Where the line `opt_slots.extend([opt._beta1_power, opt._beta2_power])  #pylint: disable = W0212` produces the error.

I do not see an 'AdamOptimizer'. I am guessing it is hiding in `opt`? How do I debug through such a thing? is there a good practice for such debugs?

I should mention I used 2to3 to convert the code to python3. Is this of any importance?

Attaching full traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "./src/compressed_sensing.py", line 177, in 
>      main(HPARAMS)
>    File "./src/compressed_sensing.py", line 21, in main
>      estimators = utils.get_estimators(hparams)
>    File "/home/erezsh/Projects/CSGM/csgm3/src/utils.py", line 98, in get_estimators
>      estimators = {model_type: get_estimator(hparams, model_type) for model_type in hparams.model_types}
>    File "/home/erezsh/Projects/CSGM/csgm3/src/utils.py", line 98, in 
>      estimators = {model_type: get_estimator(hparams, model_type) for model_type in hparams.model_types}
>    File "/home/erezsh/Projects/CSGM/csgm3/src/utils.py", line 91, in get_estimator
>      estimator = celebA_estimators.dcgan_estimator(hparams)
>    File "/home/erezsh/Projects/CSGM/csgm3/src/celebA_estimators.py", line 185, in >dcgan_estimator
>      opt_reinit_op = utils.get_opt_reinit_op(opt, var_list, global_step)
>    File "/home/erezsh/Projects/CSGM/csgm3/src/utils.py", line 545, in >get_opt_reinit_op
>      opt_slots.extend([opt._beta1_power, opt._beta2_power])  #pylint: disable = >W0212
>   AttributeError: 'AdamOptimizer' object has no attribute '_beta1_power'

Comment: can you put all traceback ?

Comment: If newer versions don't make them publicly available then it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AdamOptimizer is certainly hiding in opt: the line raising the error is only called when `isinstance` has determined that opt is an instance of `tf.train.AdamOptimizer`

```
if isinstance(opt, tf.train.AdamOptimizer):
    opt_slots.extend([opt._beta1_power, opt._beta2_power])
```

I don't think that 2to3 is to blame here, I rather expect your installed version of TensorFlow to be too new. The requirements for the `csgm` list TensorFlow 1.0.1. In this version [`_beta1_power` and `_beta2_power` have still been attributes of the AdamOptimizer.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.0/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py) This has been changed in [version 1.6](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py), now `beta1_power` and `beta2_power` are assigned locally in the functions that require them. 
You probably could get the values by calling `_get_beta_accumulators()` on the oprimizer, but then it's gonna break on the next best occasion where newer versions behave differently, I guess.

Comment: So the best way to overcome this would be to downgrade my TensorFlow?

Comment: @havakok, it's your best bet. However, the 2to3 might have still gone wrong somewhere, so you might encounter further issues. But the incompatibilities between your TensorFlow version and the 1.0.1 might be significant, so downgrading would at least help where TF is involved.